# Os.chdir with non-Latin characters

Tags: python, operating-system

While learning the os module in Python and I've come across a problem.

Let's pretend my current working directory is: `C:\Users\Москва\Desktop\Coding\Project 1`.

I'd like to change the cwd to Desktop but since the path contains some Russian letters (Москва) it throws a Syntax error:

```
print(os.getcwd()) # C:\Users\Москва\Desktop\Coding\Project 1
os.chdir('C:\Users\Москва\Desktop')
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes...
```

How shall I usually treat non-standard characters in paths and change the directory in my case?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't about the russian, it's about the backslash with u: `\U`.

When you print `os.getcwd`, escaped backslashes goes away:

```
os.getcwd()
# 'C:\\Users\\chris\\Documents\\Москва\\test'
print(os.getcwd())
C:\Users\chris\Documents\Москва\test
```

And now if you try to use the printed one by copy-paste, python will understand `\Users` part as a unicode but of course fail. You can simply reproduce by executing

```
"\Uaaaa"
```

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

You can either use raw string, or use escaped backslashes:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\sjysk\Documents\Москва')
#        ^ note `r` here
os.getcwd()
# 'C:\\Users\\chris\\Documents\\Москва'

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\sjysk\\Documents\\Москва')
os.getcwd()
# 'C:\\Users\\chris\\Documents\\Москва'
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for the help. Today I've learnt something new.